# ISCSI intiator displaying the ISCSI target even after its removal on ISCSI target server

Tags: iscsi, network-attached-storage, rhel6

I am running a ISCSI target server on RHEL 6.7 and sharing the storage for the ISCSI initiator server which is running on RHEL 6.5.

I configured the below code in the /etc/tgt/targets.conf file of the target server:

```
<target iqn.2015-12.com.example:iscsi.target100>
        backing-store /dev/sdb1
        initiator-address <intiator-ip>
</target>
```

Restarted the required services on target server. Also discovered the target from the initiator.

```
iscsiadm -m discovery -t sendtargets -p <target server>
```

The target is visible well and working fine. I mounted the volume and used it.

Later I unmounted that volume on the initiator and removed from the /etc/tgt/targets.conf file and restarted the required services and found the below command is also showing no output on target server which is expected.

```
tgtadm --mode target --op show
```

But on the initiator side, though I restarted the iscsi service, it is still showing the previous target only for the below command.

```
iscsiadm -m discovery -t sendtargets -p <target server>
```

Where from it is taking the list of targets though it is removed from the target's configuration file? How to reload the /etc/tgt/targets.conf configuration such that it should reflect on the initiator's side?